# SWIFT 3.0 and FCM: Receiving Code automatically from the cloud using on PushTry.com

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, Actually, I am done with the firebase messaging manually I am getting a message from the firebase console if I want than. But using the FCM token I need to send a message directly to the app without firebase console so how I can do that please help me with this.

I am getting this reply in pushtry.com
[image]

So, Actually, I don't know either it's working good or not. So please if you know help me out in this.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't tried pushtry before. But you could try with Postman or cURL. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/drafts/127316

Answer (score 0):

To test FCM you have to use "Google FCM Tester (iOS & Android)" but you are testing using Apple APNS

[image]